# docker-compose up via Windows bat file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm attempting to write a Windows .bat file to automate the set up of my Docker environment. My only issue seems to be the "FOR" loop line which breaks the script and, of course, never gets to docker-compose up. The second to last line is exactly as provided by the docker machine output and can be run by pasting into CMD with no issue. Is there some reason it won't work via .bat?

```
@echo off
docker-machine start
docker-machine ip > hostname.txt
set /p REN_RT_EXTERNAL_IP=<hostname.txt
del hostname.txt
echo Host-ip: %REN_RT_EXTERNAL_IP%
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env') DO @%i
call docker-compose up
```

The error thrown is: "i was unexpected at this time."

Comment: Thanks. I actually did that initially, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the `FOR` loop directly in a shell (without a script), you should be able to use the following - replace the `@%i` with just `%i`:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env') DO %i
```

Since you are running this in a `.bat` file, you have to use double percentage signs to escape the variables, like this:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker-machine env') DO %%i
```

Reference: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3023